# Extend Request interface of Express for old JS library that doesn't support typings yet

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings, overriding, vbulletin

I need [node-vbauth](https://github.com/lucasterra/node-vbauth) in a TypeScript project. Sadly, there are no types yet. So when I want to access `req.vbuser` I got an error that his property doesn't exist. To fix this, I want to provide the missing type in a `custom.d.ts`file:

```
export namespace Express {
    export interface Request {
       vbuser?: VbSessionInfo
    }
 }

export interface VbSessionInfo {
    userid: number;
    username: string;
    usergroupid:number;
    membergroupids:Array<string>;
    email:string;
    posts:number;
    subscriptionexpirydate: number;
    subscriptionstatus:number;
}
```

But this doesn't work. Typescript stil says the property `vbuser`is missing. I tried to explicitly include it in my `tsconfig.json`, no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that I'm missing to set my declaration in the global namespace and import the original Type which is going to be extended:

```
import {Request} from 'express';
declare global {
    export namespace Express {
        export interface Request {
           vbuser: VbSessionInfo
        }
     }

    export interface VbSessionInfo {
        userid: number;
        username: string;
        usergroupid:number;
        membergroupids:Array<string>;
        email:string;
        posts:number;
        subscriptionexpirydate: number;
        subscriptionstatus:number;
    }
}
```

This works perfect, including intellisense in VS Code.